# How long (if it ends at all) is the term of a moderator

Tags: support, election, moderators

How long, if elected, does a moderator serve?  I can't find any links that specify a term or time-limit.  Is it a life-long thing?

Comment: worth noting, be careful who you vote for, when someone wins you have them for a long time.

Comment: @Kortuk - Do you mean we can't shoot them if we're fed up with them?

Comment: @stevenvh: No, he's saying that shooting moderators is apparently the *only* way for the masses to get regime change around here. I don't see a problem with our current leaders currently, but remember that Hitler was originally elected too.  By the time the citizens wanted to get rid of him assasination was the only option.

Comment: @OlinLathrop so you're saying Kortuk is a nice Hitler? :)

Comment: @w5vo: I didn't say anthing about Kortuk, but I do think he's doing a fine job.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this election is for *additional* moderators, so our faithful moderators will remain at the job. Some have too little time, hence the enforcement.

It looks like we're going to be stuck with Kortuk until he dies, maybe longer.

Comment: Moderators only leave if they step down or are too ill to return to the site for an extended period, so yes, till I die or give up.

Comment: @Kortuk - That wasn't me hoping you were leaving, I just can't find it documented anywhere on SE. There are very few undocumented policies around here, so I just figured I couldn't find it. Do you have any links that address this?

Comment: @JoelB I really dont, actually, but I have discussed it with the SE employees before and know it to be true. I can get an official quote later if you want one.

Comment: @Kortuk - No worries. I spend some of the most boring parts of my day getting official quotes, with this site being the exception. It just seems like that is something worth mentioning to any prospective applicants.

Comment: @JoelB Yes, it probably is something to note, but they can step down a year or two from now and we will just have another election, that is how this one came about.

Comment: @Kortuk - I thought moderator elections were automatic at some frequency.

Comment: They contact the moderation team on a yearly frequency to ask about load. They have their own metrics and I bet they would react to other possible issues without being contacted